# How to use NStimer in a game application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nstimer

I am new to ios. And i want to make a game application. It that i need a timer which will show the time in seconds. When the user click on start button the timer should start and stop when he finish the 1st level and show the time as pop up in seconds. Can someone help? I dont know how to use. Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Before worrying about the time duration... make the game :p

Comment: what library are u using? cocos2d? or anything else? cause every library has its own methods

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use NSTimer as:-

```
-(ViewDidLoad)
{ 
NSTimer *updateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)updateTime
{
NSLog(@"....Update Function Called....");

static int i = 1;

Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];

i++;
}
```

Use this for start timer.Check it Hope it helps.Thanks :)